# MailEnable error on windows server 2008 r2 : Reason: Remote SMTP Server Returned: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for info@example.com

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, email-server, email

I am going crazy about this error message.

for some of the domains, I am receiving this error message;

> Reason: Remote SMTP Server Returned: 550 5.7.1 Unable to relay for
>   info@example.com

I am using MailEnable on windows server 2008 r2. I have just migrated the whole domain from windows server 2003 and the e-mails worked just fine there.

What would solve this problem?

Comment: Is there anything else provided in the non-delivery receipt? Can you consistently reproduce the issue when sending to certain domains?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the SMTP clients are in the authorised IP range or they're not using authentication (so the SMTP server is rightly refusing to act as an open relay).

Docs on the mail enable web site show how to configure this (SMTP properties -> relay tab).

http://www.mailenable.com/documentation/8.0/enterprise/webframe.html#smtp_props_-_relay.html

Answer (score 0):

"I have just migrated the whole domain from windows server 2003 and the e-mails worked just fine there."

Have you changed domain naming (from address) during your migration?

http://www.eudora.com/techsupport/kb/1593hq.html

Comment: not that I know of. but I am still keeping the other server alive just in case. I changed the dns though.

Comment: You might check your "return" addresses and maybe with the Black/Block Lists to ensure your server is not somehow being listed.

Comment: where can I check that?

Comment: The following is a pretty good one that covers a lot of the prevailing lists - http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx.